# requireJS does not append .js Extention to import when using new

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, typescript, requirejs

I tried to import an internal file that contains a helper class called `PagedCollection`. I tried to import it with:

```
import {PagedCollection} from "../helper/Helper";
```

and then to create an instance with new

```
this.foo= new PagedCollection();
```

but the generated output is importing the file without the js ending so the source file of ../helper/Helper is never found:

```
define(["require", "exports", "xxx", "../helper/Helper"], function (require, exports, xxx, Helper_1) {
    var fffController = (function () {
```

When debugging through the requireJS source it seems like the .js extension is never appended ( while debugging is was not able to find the reason maybe magic? )

this results in an error:

require.js:1952 GET http://localhost:***/app/helper/Helper req.load @ require.js:1952context.load @ require.js:1679Module.load @ require.js:829Module.fetch @ require.js:819Module.check @ require.js:851Module.enable @ require.js:1177context.enable @ require.js:1550(anonymous function) @ require.js:1162(anonymous function) @ require.js:131each @ require.js:56Module.enable @ require.js:1114Module.init @ require.js:783callGetModule @ require.js:1204context.completeLoad @ require.js:1583context.onScriptLoad @ require.js:1711

require.js:165 Uncaught Error: Script error for "***/app/helper/Helper"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

what i might doing wrong?

**Edit**

The Helper file:

```
import * as bar from 'barfoo';

export class PagedCollection
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: plz append the `"../helper/Helper"` snippet

Comment: the content of "helper" is added

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RequireJS not loading modules properly using karma and typescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898378/requirejs-not-loading-modules-properly-using-karma-and-typescript)